# exporting an SSRS report to Excel failure

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When trying to export an SSRS report to excel, I am getting a runtime error.  I have looked at the logs and see the following:
ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: , An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database.;

The report displays fine in Report Manager, and has run successfully in the past.

The report is only not very complex, and is approx 40 columns wide.  When I run the query in SSMS I get 27,628 records, and it takes 3 seconds to run (again, im SSMS).  The report runs fairly quickly in Report Manager also, and exporting the results to .scv format works as expected.

If any additional information is needed to help with resolving this, please let me know and I will provide it.  Thanks for you help in advance!

Additionally, report has been set to not timeout. Report runs in VS2010 and exports to Excel as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection might be timing out. Try changing the timeout length by:

1.Open the rsreportserver.config with Text Editior(e.g. Visual Studio, NotePad). By default, it is hosted in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer

2.Change the value for 'DatabaseQueryTimeout'. Valid values range from 0 to 2147483647.  A value of 0 specifies an unlimited wait time and therefore is not recommended.

3.Save the file, and then restart the Reporting Services to apply the changing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157273.aspx

Comment: Updated the timeout and that took care of it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This tip is for anyone struggling with SSRS Excel export runtime error: 
I got this error when I had a typo in my .rdl-file, namely in Language-element I had culture written wrong. Replacing it with value: =User.Language, fixed my case.

Comment: No, in the .rdl-file(XML) and there in the Language-element, like: 
<Language>fi-FI</Language>

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the config below on your web.config (main app). This change resolved my issue.

```
<location path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd">
  <system.web>
       <!-- adjust the timeout value accordingly -->
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600"/> 
  </system.web>
</location>
```